# how to pass a string to another controller (textViewController) Swift 3 using storyboards

Tags: swift, textview, tableview

1. create model

```
class model: NSObject {
    var title: String = ""
}
```

2. in method print works

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell") as! itemTableViewCell
    let person = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.itemLabel.text = person.value(forKey: "name") as? String
    m.title = cell.itemLabel.text!
    print(m.title)

    return cell
}
```

3. string not works

```
class textViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let V = ViewController()
        textView.text = V.m.title
    }

 }
```

images look here

[image: render screenshot 1]
[image: render screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the string to the new view controller using this method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AdYourIdentifierFromStoryboardHere"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? textViewController {
            destinationVC.title = title
        }
    }
}
```

This post will help you http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/